# How to save an audio stream as a wav file using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, wav, icecast

My aim is to record a radio stream coming from an Icecast server.

I am using the [icecast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icecast) node module to fetch the radio stream and then writing the wave file by piping the stream through the [wav](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav) module.

Here is an example of my code:

```
const icecast = require('icecast');
const url = 'http://87.118.104.139/radiogibsonaac';
var wav = require('wav');

let ice, fileWriter;

ice = icecast.get(url, res => {
    fileWriter = new wav.FileWriter(__dirname+'/recording.wav', {
        channels: 1,
        sampleRate: 16000,
        bitDepth: 128
    });
    res.pipe(fileWriter);
});


setTimeout(()=>{
    fileWriter.end();
    ice.end();
},5000);
```

The stream is successully recorded to my disk as expected and I am able to listen to the file in VLC, but the wav file itself does not seem to be formed correctly.

When I try to use another tool to edit the file, it shows an error each time.
For example, I am trying to change the speed of the audio on [this site](https://www.conversion-tool.com/pitch) and it does not recognise the file.

Also if I try to view the file info using the Sox CLI it displays:

> sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `recording.wav': Sorry, don't understand .wav size

Does anybody know if I am missing a step in the process of writing the wav file to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stream URL, it looks like the stream is in AAC format, and you are trying to write that data directly to a WAV file, so you end up with a file with a WAV header but AAC audio data.

You would need to either write the stream to disk as AAC, and then do a conversion on the file, or transcode the stream on-the-fly before writing it to disk.

Comment: .pipe is not a function